# Cannot properly UTF-8 encode data stored in a CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a simple script to scrape some information from a public site, and then append the data to a CSV file:

```
import requests
import base64
import csv
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

print (csv.list_dialects())

startUrl = "http://example.com?page="
#max. 964
for i in range (1,20):
    print (i)
    page = requests.get(startUrl+str(i))
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    for element in tree.xpath('//*[@class="std-link std-link--unobtrusive std-link--visitable std-bold"]/@href'):
            subpage = requests.get(element)
            subtree = html.fromstring(subpage.content)
            study = subtree.xpath('//*[@class="std-profileHero__headline"]/h1/text()')
            uni = subtree.xpath('//*[@class="std-headline std-headline--h3"]/a/text()')
            if study:
                study = study[0].replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")
                study = str(study.encode("utf-8")).strip()
            else:
                study = "-"

            if uni:
                uni = uni[0].replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")
                uni = str(uni.encode("utf-8")).strip()
            else:
                uni = "-"   

            with open("results.csv", "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
                writer.writerow([uni, study])
```

The script works, but the information stored in the CSV has ecoding problems, so I get values like these:

- b'Cat\xc3\xb3lica Lisbon School of Business
- b'Universit\xc3\xa4t Augsburg'
- b'Software Engineering'

The values are kept when I open the CSV in MS Excel 2016.

As you can see, the script encodes the strings: `.encode("utf-8")`. I also make sure the CSF file is encoded: `encoding="utf-8"`.

I tried *not* to use the `encode()` function, but then the encoding is just broken on German characters like *ü*, *ä*, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UTF8 has nothing to do with URI or XML encodings or escape sequences.. It's just *bytes*. Just make sure you set the encoding (ie *codepage) parameter to utf8 when writing your strings to a file or stream. ON THE OTHER HAND, why don't you create a *real* XLSX file with openpyxl or xlsxwriter?

Comment: Hint - this page is UTF8. View the source. No escape characters or escape sequences are used. Even if the text is clearly non-ANSI όπως αυτό εδώ

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yep, that's a good idea. I will create an Excel file directly.

Comment: Note, the reason you are getting those `b`s is because you are doing `str(study.encode("utf-8"))`. If this is python 3, then don't `.encode` the `str` to `bytes`, since `str` *are unicode*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for strange values appearing is that you're using `str(b'bytes')` instead of `str(b'bytes', encoding)`, which acts like `repr(b'bytes')` and gives you `"b'bytes'"` instead of `"bytes"`.

So, you should operate *either* entirely on `str` objects or entirely on `bytes` objects.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. So what should I use instead of this for example: `str(study.encode("utf-8")).strip()`?

Comment: Works. Amazingness.